# Highlight certain days in monthcalendar in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, eventkit, nscalendar

I need to mark date from the date where the event is started to the the date where the event is ended. I need to mark from start date to end date with some shadow on my calendar.How can I do this.

Comment: you are using the any api for use the calender integration in your application ?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have used tapku library earlier but it seems complicated so I wrote my own code for generating calendar.finally calendar has been generated but I'm unable to highlight certain dates on it.Thanks.

Comment: you check this link https://github.com/vgrichina/ios-calendar

Comment: Thanks Rushabh for your quick response. I have downloaded the code but it can not be run on simulator. when I run the code build is getting success but can't run on simulator what could be the problem?